# How can I use a RandomAccessCollection with a ForEach list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class TransactionResults: Identifiable {
    public typealias CustomClassValue = Transaction
    public typealias CustomClassIndex = Array<CustomClassValue>.Index

    public let id = UUID()
    private let transactions = sampleTransactions
}

extension TransactionResults: RandomAccessCollection {
    public var startIndex: CustomClassIndex { return transactions.startIndex }
    public var endIndex: CustomClassIndex { return transactions.endIndex }

    public subscript(index: CustomClassIndex) -> CustomClassValue? {
        get { if index >= 0 && index < transactions.count {
            return transactions[index]
            } else {
            return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it with a ForEach, I get an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'TransactionResults' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'`

```
struct TransactionListView: View {
    @State private var transactions = TransactionResults()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List() {
                ForEach(transactions) { transaction in
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change in my TransactionResults class for this to work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly declare your `Transaction` class (which by the way can conflict with SwiftUI `Transaction` type, so I would recommend to rename your type), then all is needed (at least as tested with Xcode 11.4) is to use different `ForEach` constructor:

```
ForEach(transactions, id: \.self) { transaction in
    EmptyView()
}
```

**Update:** here is a transaction class with which I tested you code snapshot (as I mentioned I renamed it to avoid conflict with built-in type)

```
class ATransaction: Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: ATransaction, rhs: ATransaction) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    let id = UUID()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to use the id of the transaction, which seems strange to me. This does fix the error tho.